# TableView not loading cells

Tags: ios, swift

My table view isn't loading the custom cells that are put into an array when I do a certain function. I know the the array contains the cells, but am at a loss as to why the cells aren't showing. It did work before but I made a few changes elsewhere in the code and now it does not work. Below is the code where I believe the error might possibly be:

@IBOutlet weak var incomeExpenseTableView: UITableView!

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    incomeExpenseTableView.reloadData()
    incomeExpenseTableView.delegate = self
    incomeExpenseTableView.dataSource = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    incomeExpenseTableView.reloadData()
}


@IBAction func addButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    let addMessage = SCLAlertView()
    addMessage.addButton("Income") {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("incomeSegue", sender: self)

    }
    addMessage.addButton("Expense") {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("expenseSegue", sender: self)
    }
    addMessage.showInfo("New Entry", subTitle: "Select either an income or expense to add")

}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let post = DATA_KEY._loadedPosts[indexPath.row]

    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IncomeExpenseCell") as? IncomeExpenseCell {
        cell.configureCell(post)
        return cell
    } else {
        let cell = IncomeExpenseCell()
        cell.configureCell(post)
        return cell
    }

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return DataService.instance._loadedPosts.count
}

func onPostsLoaded(notif: AnyObject) {
    incomeExpenseTableView.reloadData()
}
```

FYI DATA_KEY = DataService.instance

Thanks

Comment: Thought it might have been that I forgot func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }   But that doesn't seem to be the issue

Comment: It might be that you're telling the tableView to reload data but you haven't setup the delegate or datesource at the point. Try moving the tableView reloadData after the setup of datasource and delegate.

Comment: first of all set your tableview delegate and datasource

Answer (score 0):

if you have a tableviewcell's identifier named "IncomeExpenseCell", the "if let" will always be successful, why using else, you can use as! instead of as?, you don't need 'else' here, and IncomeExpenseCell() maybe will not satisfy your 'cell init'

```
 if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IncomeExpenseCell") as? IncomeExpenseCell {
    cell.configureCell(post)
    return cell
} 

let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("IncomeExpenseCell") as! IncomeExpenseCell {
    cell.configureCell(post)
    return cell
}
```